# How to bind model value to kendo.ui.Slider?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, slider

I am using kendo.ui.Slider in my MVC application as below:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Slider()
                .Name("slider") //The name of the slider is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
                .Min(0) //Set min value of the slider
                .Max(100000) //Set min value of the slider
                .Value(50000) //Set the value of the slider
                .SmallStep(1000)
                .LargeStep(10000)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:700px;" })
                        .Tooltip(tooltip =>
                        {
                            tooltip.Format("{0:n0}");
                        })
                .Events(e =>
                        {
                            e.Change("sliderOnChange");
                        })
            )
            <script>
                function sliderOnChange(e) {
                    var slider = $("#slider").data("kendoSlider");
                    var sliderValue = slider.value();
                    alert(sliderValue);
                }
            </script>
```

How can I bind the model value instead of assigning static value (.Value(50000)) here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Model**

If you have a model as follows:

```
public class AModel
{
    public int? Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

The above allows the property to be set within your action against the model.

You can then use a `SliderFor` rather than a `Slider`

**View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().SliderFor(m => m.Percentage)
                .Min(0) //Set min value of the slider
                .Max(100000) //Set min value of the slider
                .SmallStep(1000)
                .LargeStep(10000)
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:700px;" })
                        .Tooltip(tooltip =>
                        {
                            tooltip.Format("{0:n0}");
                        })
                .Events(e =>
                        {
                            e.Change("sliderOnChange");
                        })
            )
```

Notice the removed `Name` property and `Value` setter above.

As the `Percentage` property is defined in your View Model it is automatically rendered as the Slider's `Name` property.

This allows the model binder to pick it up and post the set value within your model object.

Comment: Is it possible to bind the model values to Max & Min dynamically?

Comment: @giparekh Yes, if you create another question and add it to the comments here I will answer it for you. :)

Comment: hi hutchonoid, I have created another question for my exact requirements. Please check that out. thanks!